# How to list tags matching pattern since X date?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log, git-tag

I need to list all tags matching pattern `X` that have been created after `Y` date.

I've tried the following:

```
git show --quiet $(git rev-parse --tags="linux*" --since="1 month")
```

but this lists ALL tags matching `linux*` in my repo.

I've also tried:

```
git show --quiet $(git rev-list --tags="linux*" --since="1 month")
```

this lists all tags since last month but doesn't take the pattern into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize `git log`:

```
git log --tags=linux* --since="1 month" --no-walk
```

From the [`git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---no-walksortedunsorted) documentation:

> **--no-walk** ... 
>   Only show the given commits, but do not traverse their ancestors. ...